# Default system encoding

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

When i press a keyboard key in windows (win 7) what's the encoding of the char the system sends to applications like text editor? Is it `utf-8` encoded or mayby `cp1252` for my polish language? What the `Current system locale` under `Region Settings` do and how does it affects programs like text editors?

Comment: My understanding is that it is Unicode. You can't restrict entry to only western language characters, and all cp1252 are included in Unicode. Take a look at [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). That is why you select a language/character set for non-Unicode programs.

Comment: In the Region and Language control panel click on "What is system locale? in the Administrative panel for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[WM_CHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The WM_CHAR message uses Unicode Transformation Format (UTF)-16.

The program could also listen for [WM_UNICHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646288(v=vs.85).aspx) or [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WM_KEYUP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281(v=vs.85).aspx).

In general, input in Windows is handled using window messages.

Comment: Ok i understand but as i asked what the 'Current system locale' under 'Region Settings' do and how does it affects programs like text editors?